# Function to see if a vim help file

Tags: vim

Would the following function always detect a vim help file? If not, what might be a better pattern or function to set this?

```
function IsHelpFile()
    if trim(getline('$')[0:3]) !=? 'vim'
        set filetype=markdown
        colorscheme OceanicNext
    endif
endfunction
```

For example, from:

[image: .]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this function doesn't detect help files. It detects if last line does (not?) start with pattern '.vim' (where '.' means *any character* in RegEx).

I think you wanted to check if it **does** start with it, if so then it should be

```
if getline('$') =~ '^.vim'
  " ...
endif
```

`=~` checks if left side matches regular expression on the right. `^.vim` means "*line starting with some charater followed by string 'vim'*".

But it still wouldn't detect whether the file is help file. It would detect if last line contains something what could be a modeline (`:h modeline`).

The easiest way to check if file is help page is to check its filetype:

```
function IsHelpFile()
  if &filetype == "help"
    set filetype=markdown
    colorscheme OceanicNext
  endif
endfunction
```

<sup>Note that colorscheme won't apply only to help page, but to whole Vim session</sup>

Although I discourage you from changing filetype of help file. It has a lot of special formatting and options to make it readable and easy to navigation. Changing it to Markdown will remove all of that.

Comment: where do you get the `.vim` from it? Wouldn't `[0:3]` just return `vim` ? i.e., it's using a slice of the string where the first three letters on the helpfile are `vim`? For example, see screenshot from the updated question. `!=? 'vim'` is just "not equals to 'vim'", right?

Comment: See edit (second paragraph). And yes `!=? 'vim'` does mean "_not equals to 'vim' (case insensitive)_". But why do you want to check if it doesn't equal?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. It seems for me that the first character I see usually is a space, which is why I used the trim. Can you point to a help file that starts with a `"` on the last line? https://imgur.com/a/5sBtbfm

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, of course there is no `"`, as it isn't Vim syntax, but help syntax. Although you still shouldn't check for existence of (**maybe possible**) modeline, as those aren't exclusive for help pages (for example [the one from my GDB config](https://github.com/Jorengarenar/dotfiles/blob/754ab9e7b97f4edff3e11f50c8715eaa091a2747/gdbinit#L21)).